# How to highlight same page number for two different URLs in angular 2 using routerLink

Tags: angular2-routing, routerlink

I have pagination like below. I would like to highlight page number 2 for both the below links.

```
[routerLink]="['/link/sublink2']
[routerLink]="['/link/sublink22']
```

How to achieve this using angular 2.

```
<ul class="pagination pagination-plain">

      <li [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
        <a [routerLink]="['/link/sublink1']">1</a>
      </li>
      <li [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
        <a [routerLink]="['/link/sublink2']">2</a>
      </li>
      <li [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
        <a [routerLink]="['/link/sublink3']">3</a>
      </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your html,

```
<li [class]="addActiveClass()" >
   <a [routerLink]="['/link/sublink2', '/link/sublink22']">2</a>
</li>
```

and in your component.ts file,

```
private addActiveClass() {
    let fullpath:any[]=this.router.url.split("/")
    if(fullpath[2] == 'sublink2' || fullpath[2] == 'sublink22'){ /* fullpath[2] has the second parameter after the '/'. If you want first parameter after the slash, use fullpath[1] */
      return 'active';
    }else{
      return '';
    }
  }
```

This adds an active class to the `li` when you route to the page.  You can highlight the `li.active` using css.